# "using static" throwing error

Tags: c#, using, c#-6.0, using-statement, using-directives

I'm trying to use `using static System.Console;` rather than `using System;` so I only have to type out `WriteLine("bla")` vs `Console.WriteLine("bla")`.

My code is as follows:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WriteLine("this is text")
    }
}
```

It throws the following errors:

- > Compilation error (line 1, col 7): Identifier expected; 'static' is a keyword
- > Compilation error (line 1, col 14): Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

However, when I use `using System;` and `Console.WriteLine("this is text")`, it works perfectly.

If anyone could explain what's wrong with my code, that would be great, but please explain thoroughly because I know very little about programming :S

Comment: You dont have to declare it `static`, `Console` is already `Static` class thats why you are able to access method directly using `.` operator without making object of that class. Just remove the `static` from import statement.

Comment: @CoderofCode: the OP is talking about the new `using static` feature in C# 6. It should work, assuming the latest compiler is being used.

Comment: To the OP: what version of the compiler are you using? I.e. are you actually using C# 6?

Comment: Please include the version of visual studio, compiler and any other relevant details.

Comment: These are the exact errors I get when using the C# 5 compiler.

Comment: OP:  It would have been helpful for you to report that the errors you reported seeing were generated from .NET Fiddle and _NOT_ Visual Studio / C# compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 7.0 / VS2017, the code should work, except for the error on line 7 - it's missing a terminating semicolon.

The following code compiles and runs, and displays:

> this is text

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WriteLine("this is text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, forgot the semicolon in the post, but it's there in the actual code. I guess .NET Fiddle isn't using the latest C# compiler. In visual studio, the code works fine. Thank you!